# Difference in meaning between using the compound "cansarme" and the separated "me ... cansar"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, pronombres, enclisis

> ... que está empezando a **cansarme**.
>
> ... que **me** está empezando a **cansar**.

Is it just a difference of one being stylistically better than the other? Or do they differ in meaning?

Comment: These questions might be of interest: [“Quiero comprarlo” vs “Lo quiero comprar”](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/10225/quiero-comprarlo-vs-lo-quiero-comprar) - [How do I know whether to attach a direct object pronoun to the infinitive?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/313/how-do-i-know-whether-to-attach-a-direct-object-pronoun-to-the-infinitive) - [What is more conversational - “te lo digo” or “yo quiero decírtelo”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19883/what-is-more-conversational-te-lo-digo-or-yo-quiero-decírtelo)

Comment: @ukemi Indeed, good links.  This is actually a great additional question because it *also* allows us to show partially raising.  *me está empezando a cansar*, *está empezándome a cansar*, and *está empezando a cansarme*.

Answer (score 3):

They are perfectly equivalent in modern Spanish.  Whenever you have  a personal pronoun or verb that's in the infinitive (or in the gerund) and is hierarchically linked to another verb (in this case, *empezando*, which in turn is linked to *está*), you are able to "raise" it higher in the chain —that is, bring it closer to the main verb.

You can also partially raise it, and attach it to *empezando,* although it will require an accent in such a case: "...que está empezándome a cansar".

Answer (score 1):

Examples:

> —Hay algo que está empezando a cansar**me**.
>   —Hay algo que **me** está empezando a cansar.

As @guifa said, there's no difference in meaning.

Interestingly, the other variant can be used when asked for repetition: if you said the former, when you're asked to repeat, you can say the latter.

The choice follows no rules and they are perfectly interchangeable.